# pegar valor do input e redirecionar página após submit

Tags: javascript, html

Como posso pegar o valor de um input e após o "submit" redirecionar para outra página com este valor na url?

Ex:

site.com/busca/**VALOR_BUSCA**

```
<form>
<input type="text"/>
<input type="submit" value="Pesquisar"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Pode pegar o valor pelo `id` e usa `location.href`

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="valor_busca"/>
<input type="submit" value="Pesquisar" onclick="redireciona()"/>
</form>
<script>
function redireciona(){
    var valor_busca = document.getElementById("valor_busca").value;
    location.href="site.com/busca/"+valor_busca;

}
</script>
```